# Django writing mock test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I am having problem understanding how mock works and how to write unittests with mock objects. I wanted to mock an external api calls so I can write unittests for these functions and functions which use these calls.

I tried to mock check_sms_request at first and later I need to do something with it to cover check_delivery_status for an object.

How do I write test for this cases?

Function to mock

```
def check_sms_request(remote_id, phone):
    if not can_sms(phone):
        return None

    client = Client(settings.SMS_API_URL)

    base_kwargs = {
        'phone': phone,
        'remoteId': remote_id,
    }
    request = client.service.CheckSmsRequest(settings.SMS_API_LOGIN, settings.SMS_API_PASSWORD, base_kwargs)

    return request

class SMS(models.Model):
    sms_response = models.IntegerField(choices=SMS_SEND_STATUS, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_status = models.IntegerField(choices=DELIVERY_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    has_final_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def check_delivery_status(self):
        if not self.has_final_status:
            response_status = check_sms_request(self.id, self.phone)
            if response_status is not None:
                self.history.create(fbs_status=self.sms_response, delivery_status=response_status.response)
            if response_status is not None and response_status.response in FINAL_STATUSES:
                self.has_final_status = True
            if response_status is not None:
                self.delivery_status = response_status.response
            self.save()
        return self.delivery_status
```

My test:

```
@override_settings(SMS_WHITELIST=['', ], SMS_ENABLE=True)
def test_soap_check_sms_request(self):
    check_sms_request = Mock(return_value=True)
    check_sms_request.response = SMS_SENT_AND_RECIEVED
    self.assertEqual(check_sms_request.response, SMS_SENT_AND_RECIEVED)

    obj = SMS.objects.create(**{
        'phone': self.user.phone,
        'text': u"Hello",
        'user': self.user,
        'site': self.site2,
    })
    obj.check_sms_status()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could monkey-patch the function for the test, like so:

```
@override_settings(SMS_WHITELIST=['', ], SMS_ENABLE=True)
def test_soap_check_sms_request(self):
    check_sms_request = Mock(return_value=True)
    check_sms_request.response = SMS_SENT_AND_RECIEVED
    self.assertEqual(check_sms_request.response, SMS_SENT_AND_RECIEVED)

    obj = SMS.objects.create(**{
        'phone': self.user.phone,
        'text': u"Hello",
        'user': self.user,
        'site': self.site2,
    })

    import model
    old_fn = model.check_sms_request
    model.check_sms_request = check_sms_request
    obj.check_sms_status()
    model.check_sms_request = old_fn
```

Answer (score 0):

1. test check_sms_request first

   1. mock Client
   2. retrive service and CheckSmsRequest mocks using return_value
   3. call check_sms_request
   4. check Client and CheckSmsRequest was called once with right args
2. check_sms_request should be method of a class, move it inside SMS model or just add method and call the function from this method
3. Mock this model method when testing check_delivery_status

Model:

```
class SMS(models.Model):
    sms_response = models.IntegerField(choices=SMS_SEND_STATUS, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_status = models.IntegerField(choices=DELIVERY_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    has_final_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def check_sms_request(remote_id, phone):
        if not can_sms(phone):
            return None

        client = Client(settings.SMS_API_URL)

        base_kwargs = {
            'phone': phone,
            'remoteId': remote_id,
        }
        request = client.service.CheckSmsRequest(settings.SMS_API_LOGIN, settings.SMS_API_PASSWORD, base_kwargs)

        return request

    def check_delivery_status(self):
        if not self.has_final_status:
            response_status = self.check_sms_request(self.id, self.phone)
            if response_status is not None:
                self.history.create(fbs_status=self.sms_response, delivery_status=response_status.response)
            if response_status is not None and response_status.response in FINAL_STATUSES:
                self.has_final_status = True
            if response_status is not None:
                self.delivery_status = response_status.response
            self.save()
        return self.delivery_status
```

Test:

```
class SMSModelTestCase(TestCase):

    @patch('...Client')
    def test_check_sms_request(self, ClientMock):
        client_object = ClientMock.return_value
        CheckSmsRequestMock = client_object.service.return_value.CheckSmsRequest
        sms_model = SMS() # don't save
        with self.settings(SMS_API_URL='http://example.com', SMS_API_LOGIN='kanata', SMS_API_PASSWORD='izumi'):
            sms_model.check_sms_request(101, '+11111111')
        ClientMock.assert_called_once_with('http://example.com')
        CheckSmsRequestMock.assert_called_once_with('kanata', 'izumi', '+11111111', 101)

    @patch('myproject.myapp.models.SMS.check_sms_request')
    def test_check_delivery_status(self, CheckSmsRequestMock):
        CheckSmsRequestMock.return_value = ...
        sms_model = SMS()
        ...
        sms_model.check_delivery_status(...)
```